# Generic Resource (Resx) or CustomTool Change?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, generics, resx

Currently I'm trying to extend the default Resource (resx) of a project. In the same time it would be necessary to make it available for other projects. So I had Generics in my mind and now I'm not sure if my idea is even possible.

Well let's explain.

### DB and Resx as Fallback

First Task was to create a Fallback Mechanism for DB and resx. The idea behind is the circumstance, that it could have a translation in DB, but not necessarily.

This was made by a Custom ResourceManager (with Custom ResourceReader and ResourceSet) and put this in a own Class. This wasn't a big deal.

### Custom ResourceManager and DesignTime Feature

Second Task was to make the Fields of the resx available. 
I've accomplished this by make the Resx as Base

```
internal class FallbackResource : ResxResource 
{ 
    private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;
    public static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager
    {
        get
        {
            if (resourceMan == null)
            {
                resourceMan = new CustomResourceManager();
            }

            return resourceMan;
        }
    }
}
```

With this I was able to create a "FallbackResource"-Class with access to the fields like

```
... FallbackResource.AFieldwithingApp ...
```

### So what?

Well I could use the CustomResourceManager and Implement in every new project the "FallbackResource"-Class ... Yes you're right: That's not the way.

So I thought it should be possible to create a Generic "FallbackResource" (would be first time to create an own Generics):

```
var fallbackResource = new GenericFallback<ProjectResxFile>;
... fallbackResource.AFieldofCurrentProject ...
```

During my research (I'm yet a bit new in Generics) I've got the feeling that my idea is not possible. I can use Class reference, but I cannot use a reference as base to create the "direct field access" Feature.

Am I wrong with my conclusion or do I just missing something?

Otherwise it seems I would have to consider writing an extended "ResXFileCodeGenerator". Or has somebody a better idea to accomplish the extended Resource?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion and help.